# Python : Use Popen and Communicate and get the stdout in a loop

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I want to execute bash command and get the output and I decided to use Popen and Communicate to do this. this job has to be done in a loop. The problem is that in the first round of loop every thing is OK but in the next loops I get Error when using communicate function. I know that communicate function can only be used once but I create a new subprocess each loop and therefore running communicate should be possible . 
Here's the Code:

```
with open('ComSites2.txt') as file:
for site in file:
    sf = site.split()
    temp = "http://wwww." + sf[0]
    command = "wget --spider -S '%s' 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/' | awk '{print $2}'" %temp
    print command
    output = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    StatusCode = int(output.communicate()[0])
    if StatusCode == 200:
        print "page found successfully"
    elif StatusCode == 404:
        print "Page not found!!"
    else:
        print "no result got!!"
```

when I run this I get this output :

```
wget --spider -S 'http://wwww.ACAServices.com' 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/' | awk '{print $2}'
page found successfully
wget --spider -S 'http://wwww.ACI.com' 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/' | awk '{print $2}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/AghasiTestCases/URLConnector.py", line 17, in <module>
    StatusCode = int(output.communicate()[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: `.communicate()` does work and return an empty string. The issue is with the `wget` output and your grep/awk pipeline. Are you sure, you understand what `--spyder` does? Try `wget --spyder -i ComSites2.txt` instead. There is http client in Python stdlib and tons of 3rd party packages such as `requests`.

Comment: Yes your right communicate works and the wget caused the problem. I used wget because it does HTTP redirects automatically but using these packages it will be hard to follow the redirects. However, these packages can get the status code of requests and redirects has special redirects but some use 301 as redirect status code and some others and handle these situations add more overhead and I decided to use wget instead.

Comment: If you don't know how to follow http redirects using an http client; you could ask about it instead